# Printing non ASCII glyphs in python

Tags: python

In HTML-CSS, we put non-ascii glyphs like middle dots, copyright symbol etc, by using their numeric conventions. In order to use non-ASCII characters, Python requires explicit encoding and decoding of strings into Unicode.

I have tried using unidecode lib (from reference [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/transliterating-non-ascii-characters-with-python/)), but I am having trouble printing these characters.

I have tried different conventions for the symbol:
U+25CF ,    ● [&#9679 with ';'] , and so on... (depending on variation of these glyphs)n For example sake, help me print same dot(above) in python

I want to know how to print these in python, for I have such requirement in a GUI project, made with kivy/kivymd in python.

Comment: `print("text \u25cf text")` --> `text ● text`

Comment: What version of Python are you using? In my Python 3 install, I don't require any explicit encoding or decoding of strings into unicode. I can put non-ascii characters and even emoji directly into a string literal like `print("●")`, though the situation may be a little different in Python 2.

Comment: @ymbirtt for that to work you may need to pay careful attention to the encoding of your Python source.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
print(chr(9679))
```

Just use the decimal part of the entity.

Using a special escape sequence you can embed the character in a string using the hex.

```
print('\u25cf')
```